# Generating only the audit tables of Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

The Ant task provided also creates the standard entity tables, but what if I want to create only the audit tables?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask` task generates both the audit tables and the actual entity tables and cannot be configured otherwise.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking if there's another way.